# Using credentials for Spring LDAP autentification

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, ldap, spring-ldap

There is an LDAP-server in the local network. I'm trying to autentificate users in a Spring app with Spring LDAP. There are many users and everyone should have possibility to enter their credentials in the Spring app, with which I could autentificate them to the LDAP-server.

Test code snippet for  autentification:

```
fun test() {
    val contextSource = LdapContextSource()
    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://server.com:389/")
    contextSource.setBase("DC=server,DC=com")
    contextSource.userDn = "username@server.com"
    contextSource.password = "supersecretpassword"
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet()

    val ldapTemplate = LdapTemplate(contextSource)
    ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet()

    val query = query().where("userprincipalname").`is`("username@server.com")
    ldapTemplate.authenticate(query,  "supersecretpassword")
}
```

This is a working code, user is autentificated. But here are some points I don't understand:

1. For what it is necessary to specify the login and password of the user in `LdapContextSource`, and then in `LdapTemplate` when executing autentification? It is logical, after all, if I know the user credentials, I enter them it one place. But if I don't specify the credentials in `LdapContextSource`, then when executing `ldapTemplate.authenticate(..)` I'll get an exception.  Moreover, an exception won't be thrown either when creating `LdapContextSource` either `LdapTemplate`.
   I only have an assumption that credentials in `LdapContextSource` have to be with admin rights. But for what? Knowledge of your username and password should be enough for autentification.
2. The second problem is a consequence of the first. Above, I wrote a code snippet with creating instances of the `LdapContextSource` and `LdapTemplate`. But a good point is to create beans of these classes. But I can't create beans of these classes because there are a lot of users and, accordingly, their credentials. I have to create instances of `LdapContextSource` and `LdapTemplate` every time a user logs in.

By the way, you can authenticate a user without specifying his credentials in LdapContextSource:

```
fun test() {
    val contextSource = LdapContextSource()
    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://server.com:389/")
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet()
    val dirContext = contextSource.getContext("username@server.com", "supersecretpassword")
}
```

But in this case you won't get a list of user attributes, only a list of domain attributes.

Library versions:

- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.2.0.RELEASE
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: There are 2 things at play here, 1 authentication (you are who you tell who you are) and 2. authorization. While you could do 1 with passing the username/password to LDAP you couldn't do the second as you would need to retrieve the user. Hence generally you have a readonly user to connect to the LDAP server and then let Spring through the LDAP support retrieve and validate the user. Instead of setting the `userDn` and `password` set the `authenticationSource` and set it to `SpringSecurityAuthenticationSource` which will use the entered credetials for the authentication as well as retrieval.